# Flex vertical margin between elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I am having difficulties working out how instead of having all the elements spaced out equally to instead have the elements together but still vertically centered.

[image]

i want it so there are only gaps on the outside of that content

please see my website for code

https://ukhotspot.co.uk/

Comment: You could increase the padding-top/bottom on the .carousel-caption class but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do that.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: I agree with @j08691. Always better to post the relevant code. This case is a bit of an exception, however, as the problem and solution are both clear from the image. In other words, even if the third-party link goes dead, the question retains full meaning and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `align-content: center` to your flex container.

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center; /* NEW */
}
```

When positioning a single line in the cross axis of a flex container, you can use [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items).

But when the container has multiple lines – like in the image – `align-items` is no longer useful. The `align-content` property becomes necessary.

> [**8.4. Packing Flex Lines: the `align-content`
>   property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
>
> The `align-content` property aligns a flex container's lines within
>   the flex container when there is extra space in the cross-axis,
>   similar to how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the
>   main-axis. Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex
>   container.

The reason why you have *"all the elements spaced out equally"* is because the initial value of `align-content` is `stretch`, which causes the lines to spread across evenly in the container.

There are [six different values for `align-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property). With `align-content: center`, all lines are packed in the center of the container.